# Is it possible to change the viewer parameters in A-Frame?

Tags: aframe, google-cardboard, virtual-reality, webvr

Google made it pretty easy to adjust the VR-View in Cardboard-Applications: [Viewer Profile Generator](https://vr.google.com/cardboard/viewerprofilegenerator/)
.

I would like to know if it's possible to change the VR-View of A-Frame to match different viewers with different lens to screen, inter-lens distances and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Don't think so for mobile, I believe the Viewer Generator is for native Cardboard apps. For this to happen, the browser would need a way to configure the viewer's parameters, and then from the WebVR API, A-Frame would be able to adjust automatically. But not sure which browsers implement this configuration.

Maybe on desktop, it takes the SteamVR or Oculus settings which are used in A-Frame.